# Roll dice to see who goes first in Monopoly

Tags: monopoly, dice

In Monopoly, at the start of each round players roll the dice to determine who goes first. But what if the highest number are the same for 2 or more players?

Let's say player 1 got 12 and player 2 also got 12 while others got less than that. Does the official rule states if everyone has to roll the dice again or just the highest players?

Comment: Not anything will be covered in the rules. You need to uses some kind of common sense. So you can assume, only the players tied for first place reroll.

Comment: Both systems work (as they both randomly determine who goes first). However, it's customary to only have the tied players reroll as this reduces the odds of having another tie. This would be the expected resolution method (regardless of the game).

Comment: Unless there's a good reason to select a first player non-arbitrarily, I recommend disregarding the first player selection mechanism in games. Assign each player a die value and roll only once for everybody (you might have to reroll if, for example, you roll a 6 with 5 players, but it's still more efficient) or use a handy app like Chwazi ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tendadigital.chwaziApp)) ([iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/chwazi-finger-chooser/id689674978)).

Comment: I agree with @ToonKrijthe. Use common sense and decide who goes first by fighting to the death. That way everyone wins. The survivor gets to go first and the others won't have to play Monopoly ever again

Comment: @Scherling wait... that doesn't seem right

Comment: @Scherling, great idea, monopoly can use some bloody variantion.

Comment: "at the start of each round " -- I hope you meant "at the start of the game".

Comment: Actually, it might be interesting to play a game of monopoly where each player has their own pair of dice, and everyone rolls and moves simultaneously....

Comment: That's gonna create chaos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the [official rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf) say is *" Starting with the Banker, each player in turn throws the dice.The player with the highest total starts the play: "*

However I have never seen a system for determining who goes first where if the top place is a tie all players re-roll, only the players that actually tie re-roll.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't covered by the [rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf), which simply state

> Starting with the Banker, each player in turn throws the dice. The player with the highest total starts the play

Both of the systems you propose work (since they both randomly determine who goes first). However, it's customary to only have the tied players re-roll as this reduces the odds of having another tie. This would be the expected resolution method (regardless of the game). You should seek an agreement from the other players before the initial roll if you plan to deviate from this.